# Strange vertical space with svmult and subequations environment

Tags: subequations, white-space, sv-classes

When using the class svmult and the environment subequations from amsmath, an ugly vertical space is inserted between text and formula, when a \label command is used. Moving the subequations env. in front of some text, it causes a line break.

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  Some text. 
  \begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:NNMex1Ham}
%Moving the \label command to a previous line, introduces a line breaks.
  We consider the resonant oscillator
  \begin{align}
    \ddot{x}_1 + x_1 + x_1^3 + K (x_1-x_2)^3 &= 0,\\
    \ddot{x}_2 + x_2 + x_2^3 + K (x_2-x_1)^3 &= 0,
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
  which will occur also in the next chapter.
  

  We consider the resonant oscillator
    \begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:NNMex1Ham2}
  \begin{align}
    \ddot{x}_1 + x_1 + x_1^3 + K (x_1-x_2)^3 &= 0,\\
    \ddot{x}_2 + x_2 + x_2^3 + K (x_2-x_1)^3 &= 0,
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
  which will occur also in the next chapter.

  %Now the environment without a \label command
  We consider the resonant oscillator
    \begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \ddot{x}_1 + x_1 + x_1^3 + K (x_1-x_2)^3 &= 0,\\
    \ddot{x}_2 + x_2 + x_2^3 + K (x_2-x_1)^3 &= 0,
  \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
  which will occur also in the next chapter. 
\end{document}
```

The solution `\AtBeginEnvironment{subequations}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}`found in the answer to a very similar question also solves the problem, but in the current case it cannot be applied: I am one of the authors and have no access to the editor's style files or header lines.

Comment: Why is `\AtBeginEnvironment{subequations}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}` no solution for you? You can add this line to you preamble, without changing the class.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `%` sign after `\label{}`?

Comment: Can you clarify your issue? When I compile your MWE, I see no difference in the three situations. Are you maybe using an outdated version of `svmult`?

Comment: Thank you very much! In the end, I could put \AtBeginEnvironment ... after the \begin{document} command and that solved the problem for the current article. 
Putting % after the \label command changed nothing.

I am using version 5.5 from Nov. 2018; it worked nicely with version 5.4.
Thanks for all inputs.